# How can I get all parent elements that has a certain class and their children has a certain string value in their given attributes via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I get all html parent elements that has a css class called `".example"` and their children are `<a></a>` elements containing a string value say `sample-section` in their `href` attributes via jQuery?

Here's an example:

```
<li class="example">
    <a href="root/sample-section/p01">Page 1</a>
</li>
<li class="example">
    <a href="root/sample-section/p02">Page 2</a>
</li>
<li class="example">
    <a href="root/another-section/p01">Page 1</a>
</li>
<li class="example">
    <a href="root/another-section/p02">Page 2</a>
</li>
```

I want to be able to get the first and the second `<li></li>` elements in this example (they contain the string 'sample-section') via jQuery with my above-mentioned criteria and add certain other classes to them. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a[href*=sample-section]').parent('.example');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/eG82u/

or

```
$('.example').filter(function(){
    return $(this).children('a[href*=sample-section]').length;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/kWV86/

-- Should return the same result.

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Answer (score 0):

use attribute selector with `^` which gets all the href beginning with the given text

try this..

```
 console.log($('a[href^="root/sample-section/"]').parent())
```

or the `*`selects all elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing the a given substring.

```
console.log($('a[href*="sample-section"]').parent())
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AUJfm/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('li.example > a[href*="sample-section"]').closest('li.example');
```

Comment: OP did specify that the anchors should be (direct) children of the `li`.

Answer (score 0):

In one line:

```
$('li.example a[href*="sample-section"]').parent();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pjacf/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li.example a[href*="another-section"]').each(function() {
  $(this).closest('li');
});
```